# Compare one string to all elements of an array

Tags: string, matlab

How do I get the result when '@' exist in the string will return 1 else 0. Now, I get the results of 0 0, although second string contain the character of '@'.

```
A = {'@'};

B = {'http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html',
 'http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi@dfvfv.html'};

match = strcmpi(A,B)
```

Output:
    match =

```
 0
 0
```

Desire Output 
match =

```
 0
 1
```

Edit2:

why do i use the same concept as above but i get the wrong results? I want to check whether the file that store in 'data14' got 'javascript' & 'disableclick' at the same time. But the results return me all '1'.

```
for i = 1:4
A14 = {'javascript'};
B14 = {'disableclick'};

data14 = importdata(strcat('f14data/f14_data', int2str(i)));
feature14_data=any(cellfun(@(n) isempty(n), strfind(data14, A14{1}))) & any(cellfun(@(n) isempty(n), strfind(data14, B14{1})))
feature14(i)=feature14_data
end
```

Comment: You might want to use [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be used to get desired output:

```
cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(B, A{1}))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ismember` iteratively:

```
 cellfun(@(x)ismember('@',x), B)
```